# Banshee Play Queue running haywire

Tags: music, banshee

This is strange. I love Banshee, works perfectly. Since yesterday, this has changed.

When I add album manually into the play queue, the track order gets  all jumbled up. Take a look at [this](http://i.cubeupload.com/mNX1Ei.png).

2, 7, 6, 8 ... what? They're not in that order when I select and drag them over to the queue.

The same thing happens when I use the »Fill« feature where Banshee adds content by it self.

To add insult to injury, the Play Queue doesn't even play in this jumbled order! No, it skips and jumps all over the place - often going back and playing songs it has already played. Kind of defeats its purpose.

I have absolutely no idea what is causing this. As I said, it work just a few days ago. Might have been something with an update.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me.
The easiest way to cure it, is to delete the .banshee folder in /Home/.config.
 This will set Banshee back to default & you will have to rescan your music folder again. 
 But it solved the issue.

Comment: I tried and it worked. For one reboot. Now the problem is back :(